# exposing docker container port to access from internet

Tags: docker, port

I have installed docker and have a running container with below port mapping.

0.0.0.0:32770->1414/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->4414/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->7800/tcp

I am able to open the page using http://localhost:32769 in local browser. But I am not able to open in internet using http://server_name:32769.

I have Jenkins installed on same machine and I am able to access it via nginx using http://server_name:80 over internet. Nginx installed locally and below is the setup in nginx.conf.

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8080;

            proxy_redirect     default;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  #this is the maximum upload size
  client_max_body_size       10m;
  client_body_buffer_size    128k;
  proxy_connect_timeout      90;
  proxy_send_timeout         90;
  proxy_read_timeout         90;
  proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands in Jenkins > 2.54
  proxy_set_header Connection ""; # Clear for keepalive
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a firewall set up on your host?  Does your network setup have some built-in firewalling?  If you're deploying on AWS, for instance, are your security group settings blocking the connection?  (The port mappings look plausible and so I'm guessing it's something outside Docker.)

Comment: nmap -sT -O localhost

Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): 127.0.0.1
Not shown: 984 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
25/tcp    open  smtp
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
2049/tcp  open  nfs
3389/tcp  open  ms-wbt-server
5901/tcp  open  vnc-1
5910/tcp  open  cm
6001/tcp  open  X11:1
8080/tcp  open  http-proxy
32768/tcp open  filenet-tms
32769/tcp open  filenet-rpc
32770/tcp open  sometimes-rpc3
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9

Comment: Above is the output for nmap -sT -O localhost. I can see these ports are listening. Anywhere else you want me to check?